# Swift cast protocol type to struct and pass as inout

Tags: swift, struct, protocols, inout

```
protocol ValueHolder {
}

struct A: ValueHolder {
    var value = 5
}

var x: ValueHolder = A()

func f(a: inout A) {
    a.value = 10
}
```

I want to use pass x to f. Is it possible?

**Edit:** I understand all of the staff about value semantics and inout parameters. The problem is that `x` needs to be casted to `A` and I wonder if that can be done without copying it (`as` makes a typed copy of it) so that I can use `f` on `x`.

Comment: As far as the compiler is concerned `x` is of type `ValueHolder` and has nothing to do with `A` - therefore you cannot call `f`.

Comment: Another good example for more-harm-than-good of type annotations. Delete the type anntoation of `x`, then you can call `f(a: &x)` and `x.value` prints 10

Comment: If you explain why you want to do this, an alternative solution may present itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to use pass x (and not its copy) to f. Is it possible?

Not exactly — at least, not if the parameter is an A. An A is a struct. Even with `inout`, a struct is still a value type. `inout` allows the original value to be replaced, but what it is replaced with is another A. Simply put, a struct cannot be mutated in place.

That being so, your question seems to lose its meaning. Since a struct cannot be mutated in place, there is no real reason to use `inout` here at all. You are not doing anything that *calls* for `inout`. You might as well just drop the `inout` and accept the value semantics:

```
func f(a: A) -> A {
    var a = a
    a.value = 10
    return a
}
x = f(a:x as! A)
```

If you really want to keep the `inout`, then type `a:` as a ValueHolder and cast inside the function, like this:

```
var x: ValueHolder = A()
func f(a: inout ValueHolder) {
    var b = a as! A
    b.value = 10
    a = b
}
f(a:&x)
(x as! A).value // 10
```

Comment: Note that in many cases, an `inout` parameter can be optimised to a pass by reference – which would allow a struct to be mutated 'in place'.

Comment: @matt Yes, but all I want is for `x` to change (so the fact that passing it as `inout` parameter would most likely completely replace it and not mutate it in place is fine, that's not the issue here).

Comment: Fine, but that is not what your question asked, at the time I answered it.

Comment: @Hamish I don't believe that. Putting a setter observer on the original variable shows that it is _always_ set when it is passed to an `inout` parameter. In fact, it is set even if the `inout` value is never changed! In short, `inout` may be a notational and syntactical convenience (e.g. allowing us to return a value but change another value) but it _never_ magically allows a struct to be mutated in place; there is no such thing.

Comment: @matt From the [Swift Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-ID545) – "*As an optimization, when the argument is a value stored at a physical address in memory, the same memory location is used both inside and outside the function body. The optimized behavior is known as call by reference; it satisfies all of the requirements of the copy-in copy-out model while removing the overhead of copying.*"

Comment: Of course, being an optimisation, it won't change the *observed* behaviour (e.g observers being called) – but the memory itself will be mutated in place.

Comment: @matt Take a look at the SIL (or IR) that is generated. The same physical memory address is being updated. I cannot point to the exact optimization being applied (in source), but in this case it makes sense not to allocate additional memory.

Comment: @RyanH. But wouldn't that be true anyway? If I say `struct S {var s = "hi"}; var s = S(); s.s = "ho"`, we can use the same physical memory address, but we are not "mutating in place". We are replacing the struct designated by `s` with a different struct.

Comment: @matt No, the property can be mutated directly – [take a look at the canonical SIL generated](https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/a369243158e875e5ea9d1a6e22212802) for a test case similar to the one you proposed. The property address is able to be looked up and written to directly. It's a similar story with `inout` parameters if you look at the canonical SIL generated. From what it looks like, the optimisation of an `inout` parameter from copy-in copy-out to pass by reference takes place between the raw SIL and the canonical SIL.

Comment: @matt (in addition to @Hamish last comment) Based on your example, there is no "alloc_stack" for a new `struct` with "ho". The memory address is obtained for `s.s` and a reference to "ho" (in the global strings table) is stored to said address.